# Check for duplicate record before insert in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In sql server 2005 I have a table like this

```
empno             name          project
--------       --------       -----------
1               ram              pro-1
2               sheik            pro-2
```

Now I want to raise error when I try to insert record with empno and project values already present in table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If exists then `RAISERROR` unless insert accordingly, code block is given below:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM targetTable AS t
     WHERE t.empNo = @yourEmpNo
         AND t.project = @yourProject)
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('Raising errors',18,1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO yourTable (empno, name, project)
      SELECT @empno, @name, @project
END
```

Comment: This is also the wrong solution, see my comment on the solution of Adam

Answer (score 3):

If you want to raise an error, you could put a [UNIQUE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) or [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) on `(empno, project)`  When you try to `INSERT` a value that conflicts with the `INDEX/CONSTRAINT` an exception will be thrown.

Alternatively you can insert if the record doesn't exist or update `name` if it is already in the table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM yourTable AS t
             WHERE t.empNo = @yourEmpNo
                AND t.project = @yourProject)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO yourTable (empno, name, project)
   SELECT @empno, @name, @project
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   UPDATE t
   SET t.Name = @name
   FROM yourTable AS t
   WHERE t.empno = @empno
      AND t.project = @project
END
```

Comment: Adam, your alternative solution is incorrect. You can not be sure that the parallel thread will not insert same row after your code [IF NOT EXISTS] and before your [INSERT]. For this to work correctly you must open the transaction, lock the entire table, check record, and only then do the insertion. Another alternative is to write smart trigger with checking duplicates on insert / update.